# How can I launch a Windows application using HTML button?

Tags: html, windows, launch

I have HTML page with button and I want to run `Calculator` from [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) when I click that button (launch the app when button is clicked). How can I do that?

Comment: There are tons of similar questions already asked on SO.

Comment: @JJF Can you give me at least one example of those "tons of similar questions" ? :)

Comment: Did you google this? What did you try so far? Post your code! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What are you having problems with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call below JavaScript function on click of your HTML button.

```
 function RunFile() {
    WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
    WshShell.Run("C:/windows/system32/calc.exe", 1, false);
 }
```

**Note** :Only works on IE

Comment: Is there a way to make it work on Chrome? Thx for the code.

Comment: You can refer this link https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendNativeMessage